# Querying a value from two related table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have related tables events and tickets which are related

```php
class Event {
  public function tickets(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
  }
}

class Ticket {
  public function events(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
  }
}
```

I have a store function getting data from and route URL

```php
$ticket=new Ticket;
$ticket->userName= $request->input('userName');
$ticket->userEmail= $request->input('userEmail');
$ticket->phoneNumber= $request->input('phoneNumber');
$ticket->regular_quantity= $request->input('regular_quantity');
$ticket->vip_quantity= $request->input('vip_quantity');
$ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
```

I have a variable `max_attendees` which I want to query the maximum attendees which is a column in events table where event id is

```php
$ticket->event_id=$request->route('id');
```

query

```php
$maximum_attendants=\App\Models\Event::with('Max_attendies')->where('id','=='$event_id');
```

events table
[image]

I have tried this but giving me syntax error, **unexpected 'event_id' (T_STRING), expecting ')'**

Comment: What is this `::with('Max_attendies')` supposed to mean? Do you have such relation in `Event` model? Or is it just a column in `events` table? Are you trying to find `Ticket` for some `Event` and get Event's `Max_attendies` column?

Comment: its a column in events table i want to get the value of max_attendies  which is a column in events table

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `,` in your where clause:

```
where('id','==', $event_id)
```

Comment: hey i've changed it and echo $Max_attendies now am getting Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Comment: because `$Max_attendies` is not a string so you are getting error, you can not `echo` class object

Comment: how do i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting attendance from your 'tickets' table, you can use relation to count,

```
$event = Event::find($id);
$event->tickets()->count();
```

Comment: noo actually am not trying to get the maximum number am getting the value of attendants for an event

Comment: are you trying to count all the attendance from a specific event?

Comment: the value is already input in the events table each event has a specific number of people i want the value according to the event_id which will be stored the variable max_attendies

Comment: Can you share your table structure?